# Serial port: stuck in read()

Tags: serial-port, port, communication

I have a C++ program that reads a IMU device and writes the data after some processing to a file.
The rate is quit high, 500 lines per second. The program seems to work fine, however it randomly stops reading the serial port.

After some research it seems like it is stuck inside the read command:

```
while((res += read(IMU, header, 3)) != 3).
```

How can this happen and how can I prevent this from happening?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

```
void* imuLogger(void* arg) {
IMU = initSerial("/dev/ttyUSB0", B115200);
openLog("logIMU", IMUfile);
int res;
char tmp;
char header[3];

while(true)
{
    gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
    timeLog = (ts.tv_sec * 1000000 + ts.tv_usec) - timeStart;

    /**** READ IMU ****/
    res = 0;
    cout << indexLog << "-"<< IMU<< endl;
    while((res += read(IMU, header, 3)) != 3);
    cout << indexLog << "entered loop"<< endl;
    string head(header, 3);


    if(head.compare("snp") == 0 || head.substr(1, 2).compare("np") == 0 || head.substr(0, 2).compare("sn") == 0 || (header[0] == 's' && header[2] == 'p'))
    {

        buf[0] = 's';
        buf[1] = 'n';
        buf[2] = 'p';

        while((res = read(IMU, &tmp, 1)) != 1);
        buf[3] = tmp;

        res = 4;
        while(res < sizeof(buf))
            res += read(IMU, buf + res, sizeof(buf) - res);

        parseData();
    }
    else if(head.substr(0, 2).compare("np") == 0)
    {

        buf[0] = 's';
        buf[1] = 'n';

        buf[3] = buf[2];
        buf[2] = 'p';

        res = 4;
        while(res < sizeof(buf))
            res += read(IMU, buf + res, sizeof(buf) - res);

        parseData();
    }
    else if(head.substr(1,2).compare("sn") == 0)
    {

        buf[0] = 's';
        buf[1] = 'n';
        buf[2] = 'p';

        while((res = read(IMU, &tmp, 1)) != 1);
        while((res = read(IMU, &tmp, 1)) != 1);
        buf[3] = tmp;

        res = 4;
        while(res < sizeof(buf))
            res += read(IMU, buf + res, sizeof(buf) - res);

        parseData();
    }
    else
    {
        //tcflush(IMU, TCIOFLUSH);
        //while((res = read(IMU, header, 1)) != 1)
        //  cout << 
        cout << "Error parser\n";
    }
//parseData();
        //gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
        //timeEnd = (ts.tv_sec * 1000000 + ts.tv_usec) - time - timeStart;
        //cout << "Length:" << res << " Time:" << timeEnd << " Address:" << (int)packet.Address << endl;
        //usleep(10000 - timeEnd);

//cout <<"entered"<< endl;
    }
return 0;
}

int main() {

    signal(SIGINT, exit_handler);

    gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
    timeStart = ts.tv_sec * 1000000 + ts.tv_usec;

    pthread_create(&imuThread, NULL, imuLogger, NULL);
    pthread_create(&rpmThread, NULL, rpmLogger, NULL);
    //pthread_create(&baroThread, NULL, baroLogger, NULL);

    while(true)
    { 
        gettimeofday(&ts4, NULL);
        timeLog_main = (ts4.tv_sec * 1000000 + ts4.tv_usec) - timeStart;
        cout << timeLog_main/1e6 << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to describe the hardware in more detail as it may be a quirk of one specific device. What is an "IMU" and does it uniquely describe one type of device?

Comment: Yess of coarse the IMU is a CHR-UM6, https://www.chrobotics.com/shop/orientation-sensor-um6.

Comment: It is in broadcast mode, meaning it sends data all the time. I have written a program in JAVA which did exactly what I wanted however, it was to slow to run on a Raspberry PI. Therefor I've rewritten it into C++, and now bumped into this strange instability. The reason for the raspberry is that it has to fly along while logging.

Answer (score 0):

If `read()` returns 1 byte the first time around, and 3 bytes the second time around, then `res` is never 3.